# Hungarian algorithm in Python for non-square cost matrices

Tags: python, numpy, hungarian-algorithm

I want to use the Hungarian assignment algorithm in python on a non-square numpy array.

My input matrix `X` looks like this:

```
X = np.array([[0.26, 0.64, 0.16, 0.46, 0.5 , 0.63, 0.29],
              [0.49, 0.12, 0.61, 0.28, 0.74, 0.54, 0.25],
              [0.22, 0.44, 0.25, 0.76, 0.28, 0.49, 0.89],
              [0.56, 0.13, 0.45, 0.6 , 0.53, 0.56, 0.05],
              [0.66, 0.24, 0.61, 0.21, 0.47, 0.31, 0.35],
              [0.4 , 0.85, 0.45, 0.14, 0.26, 0.29, 0.24]])
```

The desired result is the matrix ordered such as `X` becomes `X_desired_output`:

```
X_desired_output = np.array([[0.63, 0.5 , 0.29, 0.46, 0.26, 0.64, 0.16], 
                             [0.54, 0.74, 0.25, 0.28, 0.49, 0.12, 0.61], 
                             [[0.49, 0.28, 0.89, 0.76, 0.22, 0.44, 0.25], 
                             [[0.56, 0.53, 0.05, 0.6 , 0.56, 0.13, 0.45], 
                             [[0.31, 0.47, 0.35, 0.21, 0.66, 0.24, 0.61], 
                             [[0.29, 0.26, 0.24, 0.14, 0.4 , 0.85, 0.45]])
```

Here I would like to maximize the cost and not minimize so the input to the algorithm would be in theory either `1-X` or simply `X`.

I have found https://software.clapper.org/munkres/ that leads to:

```
from munkres import Munkres

m = Munkres()
indices = m.compute(-X)

indices
[(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 3), (4, 0), (5, 1)]

# getting the indices in list format
ii = [i for (i,j) in indices]
jj = [j for (i,j) in indices]
```

How can I use these to sort `X` ? `jj`only contain 6 elements as opposed to the original 7 columns of `X`.

I am looking to actually get the matrix sorted.

Comment: Your input matrix only has six rows, so the solution will only have six results. What are you trying to sort? `indices`?

Comment: Indeed the dimensions are not the same (non-square matrix) and this was the problem. I found a solution and just posted it to help other people having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some hours working on it, I found a solution. The problem was due to the fact that `X.shape[1] > X.shape[0]`, some columns are not assigned at all and this leads to the problem.

The documentation states that

> "The Munkres algorithm assumes that the cost matrix is square.
> However, it’s possible to use a rectangular matrix if you first pad it
> with 0 values to make it square. This module automatically pads
> rectangular cost matrices to make them square."

```
from munkres import Munkres

m = Munkres()
indices = m.compute(-X)

indices
[(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 3), (4, 0), (5, 1)]

# getting the indices in list format
ii = [i for (i,j) in indices]
jj = [j for (i,j) in indices]

# re-order matrix
X_=X[:,jj]  # re-order columns
X_=X_[ii,:] # re-order rows

# HERE IS THE TRICK: since the X is not diagonal, some columns are not assigned to the rows !
not_assigned_columns = X[:, [not_assigned for not_assigned in np.arange(X.shape[1]).tolist() if not_assigned not in jj]].reshape(-1,1)

X_desired = np.concatenate((X_, not_assigned_columns), axis=1)

print(X_desired)

array([[0.63, 0.5 , 0.29, 0.46, 0.26, 0.64, 0.16],
       [0.54, 0.74, 0.25, 0.28, 0.49, 0.12, 0.61],
       [0.49, 0.28, 0.89, 0.76, 0.22, 0.44, 0.25],
       [0.56, 0.53, 0.05, 0.6 , 0.56, 0.13, 0.45],
       [0.31, 0.47, 0.35, 0.21, 0.66, 0.24, 0.61],
       [0.29, 0.26, 0.24, 0.14, 0.4 , 0.85, 0.45]])
```